# how can I initialize a variable in array type and how can I give values to that?

Tags: python, image-processing

I have an image and I want to find the median in blocks and then show it. here is my code:

```
img = cv2.imread('pic.png', 0)

win = 5   
height, width = img.shape    

MedianOfBlock = {}  

for i in range(0, (height-2*win)):
  for j in range(0, (width- 2*win)):
     block = np.array(img[i:i+win, j:j+win])

     # Compute the median in each window
     MedianOfBlock[i,j] = np.median(block)
```

But for further processing, MedianOfBlock should be in array type. not in dictionary type. How can I do it? or is there a way I do the above processing in array form not in dictionary type? ie how can I initialize MedianOfBlock as array an assign values to that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you know the dimensions, you can do:

```
height_max = height - 2 * win
width_max = width - 2 * win
array_form = [
  [ MedianOfBlock[i,j] for j in range(width_max) ] for i in range(height_max)
]
```

But I recommend you to simply use a matrix data structure from the beginning:

```
img = cv2.imread('pic.png', 0)

win = 5   
height, width = img.shape

MedianOfBlock = []

for i in range(height-2*win):
  MedianOfBlock.append([])
  for j in range(width-2*win):
     block = np.array(img[i:i+win, j:j+win])

     # Compute the median in each window
     MedianOfBlock[i].append(np.median(block))
```

Answer (score 0):

Would the following work for you? It should form a list of lists

```
mg = cv2.imread('pic.png', 0)

win = 5   
height, width = img.shape    

MedianOfBlock = []

for i in range(0, (height-2*win)):
  row = []
  for j in range(0, (width- 2*win)):
     block = np.array(img[i:i+win, j:j+win])

     # Compute the median in each window
     row.append(np.median(block))

  MedianOfBlock.append(row)
```

And accessing it would be the same way as in your code

```
MedianOfBlock[i][j]
```

Comment: sorry I have one more question with this code. as I am checking my results, for example I habe a block that all the 25 values are set to 0. However the median result for that is for example 93!!!! why? it should be 0. why is is showing false results?

Comment: You mean media of twenty five 0 values is coming out to be 93? Can you debug at row.append and provide the block's value?